# How do I set the content of a Kendo window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have this window:

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Window()
  .Name("errorWindow") 
  .Title("")
  .Content(@<text>
            //Put text here
     </text>)
  .Draggable() //Enable dragging of the window
  .Resizable() //Enable resizing of the window
  .Modal(true)

  .Visible(false)
  )
```

which is converted to this on the client:

```
jQuery(function(){jQuery("#errorWindow").kendoWindow({"modal":true,"iframe":false,"draggable":true,"pinned":false,"title":"","resizable":true,"content":null,"actions":["Close"]});});
```

Which I can call with this JScript:

```
function onAjaxFailure(data) {
        var window = $("#errorWindow").data("kendoWindow");
        window.center().open();
    }
```

But how do I put the text in the window?  In other words, the "data" parameter will be the text to be shown in the error windows.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`kendoWindow.content(data)`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window#methods-content), e.g.:

```
$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
    modal: true,
    visible: false,
});

setTimeout(function () {
    var kendoWindow = $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");
    kendoWindow.content("show this");
    kendoWindow.center().open();
}, 2000);
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/x6RBt/))

If you want it to show in a certain element inside the window, you can search for it in `kendoWindow.element`.

Comment: I have some trouble with this solution. I'm loading a PartialView with other kendo widgets into the window and I'm getting JavaScript errors and the widgets are not displayed correctly.